# Netbeans Cordova Build failed error 1: The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project

Tags: java, android, cordova, netbeans

I've created an Hello World project in Netbeans 8.0.2 but my problem is I want to launch it on my smartphone and it shows that my SDK tools build revision is too low for my project (it is 19.0.3 and it needs 19.0.1)

I don't understand this error !

> Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\Mounir\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testNirmou\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat 
>   ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\Mounir\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testNirmou\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\Mounir\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:483: The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project 'MainActivity'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
>
> Total time: 1 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the Android SDK Manager and install the newer SDK Build Tools. The current build tools is version 22.0.1.

```
 C:\Users\Mounir\android-sdks\SDK Manager.exe
```

More details about the SDK Manager: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html